# Как в в дочернем потоке неявно использовать родительский TreadLocal?

Tags: java, kotlin

У меня есть такой код:

```
val threadLocal = ThreadLocal<Map<String, Int>>()

fun main() {

    threadLocal.set(mapOf("foo" to 1))
    threadLocal.set(threadLocal.get().plus("bar" to 2))
    thread {
        threadLocal.get().plus("baz" to 3)
    }
    sleep(1000)

    println(threadLocal.get())
}
```

В ответ получаю такое сообщение:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: threadLocal.get() must not be null
    at basic.DemoKt$main$1.invoke(Demo.kt:16)
    at basic.DemoKt$main$1.invoke(Demo.kt)
    at kotlin.concurrent.ThreadsKt$thread$thread$1.run(Thread.kt:30)
{foo=1, bar=2}
```

А я хотел бы видеть такое:

```
{foo=1, bar=2, baz=3}
```

При этом было бы хорошо, если дочерний поток не думал бы о родительком. Он просто знает, что есть инициализированный `ThreadLocal` и работает с ним.

Answer (score 0):

[`ThreadLocal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) нужен именно для того, чтобы изолировать между потоками данные:

> These variables differ from their normal counterparts in that each thread that accesses one (via its get or set method) has its own, independently initialized copy of the variable.

То есть для решения вашей задачи нужно использовать [`AtomicReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html), например:

```
val common = AtomicReference<Map<String, Int>>()

fun main() {
    common.set(mapOf("foo" to 1))
    common.set(common.get().plus("bar" to 2))
    thread {
        common.set(common.get().plus("baz" to 3))
    }
    sleep(1000)

    println(common.get())
}
```